# Application taking lot of CPU

Tags: android, performance

I have android application and doing an application performance test using android studio. What i have seen in Method Tracing that almost 57% of CPU is showing in android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage. I am using different handler inside of my application, Why these are consuming so much CPU even when application is not in use?  Actually I want to see which part of my application consuming so much CPU to figure out why application consuming more battery. How i can reduce the CPU time on these kind of call. Here is a screen shot of a trace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your device using most of JVM and upon requirement CPU.
There can be a lot of reason such as ,

1. Java Classes may too big (Line Number is too high)
2. Layout UI may be difficult to draw(too much view - layout -layout
   layout like this)
3. Maybe too big parcelable objects ....

Btw really hard to say something without seeing code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I have figure out a problem is with animation inside of my application.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Touching views visibility , position like these inside threads(handlers) may reduce your application performance. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html